# Randomly select word from list while excluding a value(s) from list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to be select a word from a list while excluding a previous random selection from the same list.

Tried to modify the following [suggestion](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/157520-randbetween-excluding-values.html) to meet my needs with no luck.

`=SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($G2,$A$20:$A$34,0)),"",$A$20:$A$34),INDEX($A$20:$A$34,RANDBETWEEN(1,ROWS($A$20:$A$34)),1))`

**List**

```
Apple
Orange
Kiwi
Grape
```

**Desired Outcome**

```
Selection 1 (Random)    Selection 2 (Random - exclude selection 1)    Selection 3 (Random - exclude selection 1 & 2)

          Kiwi                    Apple                                       Orange
```

**Not Desired Outcome 1**

```
Selection 1 (Random)    Selection 2 (Random - exclude selection 1)    Selection 3 (Random - exclude selection 1 & 2)

          Kiwi                     Kiwi                                          Orange
```

**Not Desired Outcome 2**

```
Selection 1 (Random)    Selection 2 (Random - exclude selection 1)    Selection 3 (Random - exclude selection 1 & 2)

          Kiwi                     Apple                                        Apple
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the flexibility to add some additional columns, add columns to the left of the list : one generates a random number [0..1) with `=RAND()`. The other uses `RANK.EQ` on the random number for the row across the set of random numbers for the list to generate an order - ie, a randomized ordering of the list. A simple `VLOOKUP` can be used to pick off the first choice, second choice .. etc.

Comment: could you flush this out some more.  I get the gist of what you are saying, but I am not familiar with RANK.EQ so what I am trying is blowing up in my face  I keep getting errors with the rank.eq equation.

Comment: @ForwardEd, see this [link](https://www.got-it.ai/solutions/excel-chat/excel-tutorial/random/how-to-use-the-randbetween-function-with-no-duplicates)

Comment: @JvdV  thanks.  Much clearer.  I had tried with rand and rand between and both were blowing up in my face.  The no duplicate portion was part of what was missing.  with rand() its possible to get duplicate values but highly unlikely.